# How to restrict Jenkins credentials to Github organisations in multibranch projects?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials, directory, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up a Jenkins server which builds multiple projects using "Github Organisation" Items. I now want to restrict some credentials so they can only be used in specific organisations.

I figured this should be possible, since such a Multibranch project just creates folders and the folder plugin integrates with the credentials plugin.

However, I have not found any documentation on how to restrict credentials to folders (only that it is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found out myself.

While being in a folder (or github organisation/multibranch project), click on "Credentials" (left sidebar).
After that, the same credentials entry gets a child entry, called "Folder". Click on it, and you can edit the credentials(-domains) scoped to the folder like usual.

Current Limitation: The folder plugin does only support "Username with password" credentials.